# RegEx Split String and Leave Delimiter

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to split a string and leave the delimiter intact. I am getting pretty close but I can't figure it out fully. I have found a lot of examples on Stack Overflow but I am still running in to an issue that I can't figure out. Here is the code:

```
"This is a string with ${G:VarSome:G} text".split(/\$\{(.+?(}\(.+?\)|}))/g)
```

The above code yields:

```
['This is a string with ', 'G:VarSome:G}', '}', ' text']
```

The result I am looking for is:

```
['This is a string with ', '${G:VarSome:G}', ' text']
```

The ${G:SomeVar:G} pattern is a templating system where variables will be injected. There are other formats of variables too for example ${G:AnotherVar:1}, ${G:DifferentVar:5} etc. After I get the split string, I will do a variable lookup in the system to inject the corresponding variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are having an extra capture group inside the regex, this will give you a single group.

```js
const result = "This is a string with ${G:VarSome:G} text".split(/(\${.+?})/g);

console.log(result);
```

The regex that graps a single capture group looks like this. it returns all the captured inside `()`

`/(\${.+?})/g`

This should capture the examples provided. [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/iI0QMu/1)

It's build with first getting
`${` and then getting one or more characters lazily (`.+?`) until it encounters a `}`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex for splitting:

```
/(\${[^}]*})/
```

**Code:**

```js
var s = 'This is a string with ${G:VarSome:G} text';
var arr = s.split(/(\${[^}]*})/);

console.log(arr);
```

Here:

- `\${[^}]*}`: Will match `${` followed by 0 or more non-`}` characters followed by `}`